# Porting Android to run on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-source

I've recently started looking into running Android on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and have been pretty disappointed with what already exists (e.g. the [RT Android](https://rtandroid.embedded.rwth-aachen.de/downloads/raspberry-pi/) project is dead and has been replaced with a paid product, and [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/index.html) isn't *really* Android). As a result, I started looking into porting AOSP from scratch to run on the Pi. I've downloaded the AOSP master branch and have poked around in the code enough to conclude that I have basically no clue what I'm doing.

So, my question is: **if I were to port AOSP to the Pi, what all would that entail?**

I realize that getting anywhere close to a fully functional system is probably way outside the realm of possibility for a single person, but if someone could just humor I would appreciate it, if for no other reason than my own education (and maybe to help more qualified people who might have this same question in the future).

I have a limited knowledge of processor architecture, some lower level programming experience in the form of embedded C, and higher level experience writing Android apps (and a plethora of other things), but essentially no knowledge of operating systems, so you'll probably want to start pretty basic with your answers.

The main things I'd like to know are:

- what drivers I would have to write, assuming I want to be able to use wifi, ethernet, hdmi, usb ports, bluetooth, GPIO, etc.
- how I would go about figuring out how to write those drivers (the main functions I'm interested in are hdmi, wifi, bluetooth, and GPIO, so using one of those as an example would be particularly helpful)
- any other major steps I'd need to take to get Android running on the Pi
- even any learning I would need to do, for instance about the linux kernel, or operating systems in general, or anything else (I don't really know enough yet to know what all I don't know)

I'm assuming I would start with the generic arm64 AOSP build since the Pi's processor has a 64 bit ARM architecture (ARM Cortex-A53, specifically), but beyond that I'm not really sure.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

p.s. I have no problem using all/part of pre-existing drivers and whatnot -
 if it's possible to steal code from some other Pi OS then I'm all for it, although I'd still like to know the broad strokes of how to do this from scratch.

Comment: You are in the realm of 'embedded Android' and 'porting AOSP to xyz device'. As these require lots of different skills, your best bet is to search on those topics (especially what it takes to get a open source video driver on the Raspberry Pi) Also see [Why is there no Android on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79856/26706) And did you not find this: http://konstakang.com/devices/rpi3/CM14.1/

Comment: This question is [way too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have to agree this is "too broad".  If you really wanted to do this, you should probably try to recombine platform-unique code from Android Things back into ordinary AOSP.  But the biggest question you need to consider is **Why?**   What is the basis for thinking this is a good idea?  If you want an ordinary Android platform there are lots to choose from.

Comment: @MorrisonChang hadn't come across LineageOS before, thanks!

Comment: @Litty yeah, I knew it was pretty broad, but couldn't think of a better place to ask the question

Comment: @Chris as for why, it was more curiosity about how to do this than a desire to actually fully implement everything. And your idea about Android Things occurred to me as well, but it's still in the developer preview stages which, as far as I know, means the source code is largely unavailable. Once they have an official release version I think they'll open up the github repository to the public